# Can we have two simultaneous udp streams between 2 specific pairs of IPs and Ports?

Tags: network-programming, udp, wireshark, rtp

I'm trying to inspect and analyze my network traffic. Suddenly I found something confusing. I was thought that packets are splited to streams based on their `(SRC_IP, DES_IP, SRC_PORT, SRC_PORT , PROTOCOL_NUM)`. But now I found two groups of packets with equal above features but interpreted as two different streams in Wireshark:

As you see below, the `RTP` packets with even packet numbers are a single stream and the `RTP` packets with odd packet number are another stream, while both has equal `(SRC_IP, DES_IP, SRC_PORT, SRC_PORT , PROTOCOL_NUM)`. Why?

**To compare the statistics:**

[image]

[image]

**They are interpreted as two different streams:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are just looking at the UDP traffic from either direction. UDP stream 2 is from `192.168.1.162` to `192.168.1.159` and UDP stream 3 is from `192.168.1.159` to `192.168.1.162`.

While there are two UDP streams, there is only one RTP session. This is because the RFC protocol states that you cannot multiplex on the same port. From [RTP RFC Section 5.2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt).

```
In RTP, multiplexing is provided by the destination transport address
(network address and port number) which is different for each RTP session.
```

So, yes there are two simultaneous UDP streams, but it is just both hosts talking to each other during a RTP session.